# how to add grayscale in CSS without filtering?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html2canvas

Html2Canvas works perfectly to make div content download, but when the div contains CSS filters the html2Canvas not apply the filters in the generated image. so any another solution for filtering and outline applied in div content.

Comment: You can make stuff greyscale by overlaying black and setting `mix-blend-mode: saturation;`. An ::after pseudo element would be suitable for this, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can also apply with the use of this, you can change your background color as per your choice, Hope it works for you.

```css
.class-name { 
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  z-index: 1;
}
```